# How to remove all `input` elements which are lager then this one who calls the function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to remove all `input` element until `for loop` is reatching the one how trigger the function.

Issues, can i use the `remove` to delete it from the dom?
second issue it is possible to select the ´class´ so that I can delete/remove it? 
They all have the same `classname`.

I create new `INPUT` and insert the `ID` in an `ARRAY`

```
function child_input(element) {
  if (order_input.length-1 == 2) {
    alert("ritch lenght")
    return false;
  }
  if (order_input.length-1 >= 2) {
    alert("Fail!!")
  }
  element = document.createElement('input');
  element.type = "number";
  element.classList.add('dropNew');
  element.id = "input"+counter+"";
  element.onmouseleave = function mouseLeave() {
    if (element.value != "") {
      element.readOnly = true;
      element.classList.add('unWriteable');
      element.onmouseleave = false;
      child_input();
      element.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
        element.classList.remove('unWriteable');
        element.readOnly = false;
        element.onmouseleave = function() {
          //hier würde ich immer den input(child) vorigen löschen...
          mouseLeave();
          removeChild_input(this.id);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('.Main_Div').append(element);
  order_input.push(element);
  counter++;
}
```

It can be know a little bit difficult to understand!!
If I now `dbclick` one of these four `input` (example the second one) I would like the following input to be deleted. (number 4,3 have be to removed).

```
  //hold the oldest, and remove all child
    let delete_item = document.querySelector('#'+ id);
    let num_id = id.replace("input", " ");
    num_id = parseInt(num_id);

    for (var i = order_input.length-1; i >= num_id; i--) {
      order_input.slice(-1);
      order_input.pop();
      document.querySelector(".dropNew")[i].remove();
    }
    console.log(order_input.length-1);
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue, a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so. For that, we'll need the HTML in addition to enough JavaScript to understand the situation. For instance, what is `order_input`? Note that you probably don't want a space in a string you're going to call `parseInt` on; so replace "input" with "", not " ".

Comment: so i hope it will be more clear. @HereticMonkey

Comment: I've read your question a few times and have no idea what you're trying to do or why, let alone what the issue is.

Comment: I would like to remove element form my body. When i start to edite for example the first one. I would like to remove the 3 and 2 `input`. @Amy

Comment: Still not seeing any HTML, nor how these functions are called. It appears as though English may not be your primary language; it may be worth some effort trying to find someone who speaks English a bit better to help you. The phrases you are using, "How can I remove specific until a number" and "until this which was clicked" have little meaning in English.

Comment: @HereticMonkey    so if u still have problems to understand my issue than im sorry i did my best ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `document.querySelectorAll('+class+')[i].remove()`

whole function.., 
to delete until the input which trigger the function.

```
for (var i = order_input.length-1; i >= num_id; i--) {
      order_input.slice(-1);
      order_input.pop();
      document.querySelectorAll(".dropNew")[i].remove();
    }
```

wish u guys a good night.
 Thx for the help. refocus ;)